# Android Toolbar behind Status Bar on API 19

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have been struggled with this for days now and have not found out a solution yet. I have a NavigationDrawer activity with a Toolbar and several fragments, simple as that. Inexplicably, the Toolbar remains behind the Status Bar **ONLY on Android 4.4** (API 19).

[image]

I have used *everything* I found, I even copied the code from another apps where this is working but nothing changed.

This is all relevant code:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            useProguard false
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'

    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'

    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.3'

    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
}
```

**Android manifest**

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Base.AppTheme">

    <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Base.AppTheme.Main"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

</application>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base -->
    <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_activity</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Main Activity -->
    <style name="Base.AppTheme.Main">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/background_navigationDrawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_version"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text="Version 0.0.0"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_drawer_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextView.Toolbar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_logo"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_toolbar"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbat_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <include layout="@layout/component_loading_spinner" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer_main" />
```

**fragment_browser.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView/>
```

**What am I doing wrong?? What am I have to do on API 19 to have `fitSystemWindows` working so `Toolbar` is placed below status bar?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The problem was that I was overriding the `themes` in a `styles-v19.xml` and I had this line added:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Once removed this, the Toolbar works perfect. I'll update the styles snippet to include this just in case someone still found this post useful.